# How to disable Ctrl+Alt+Left/Right on KDE?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, centos, kde, intellij-idea

I need <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ (<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>)  to be bound to IntelliJ IDEA but something is preventing the combination to reach IDEA. I searched everywhere but I only found information about Gnome and Ubuntu, I'm using KDE with CentOS.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+ (<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>) are also blocked by something that I don't know and it's really slowing me down.

I think I'm using KDE4 because I see some kde4 commands in terminal.

Output of `kde4-config --version`:

```
Qt: 4.8.7
KDE Development Platform: 4.14.8
kde4-config: 1.0
```

Comment: Ubuntu (w Gnome) 20.04 has "Settings > Keyboard shortcuts > ...", does KDE maybe have something similar? Before 20.04 there was "only" a tweak tool that available.

Comment: "Most of the key-bindings (shortcuts) are configurable in the Settings → Configure Shortcuts menu, if you like to use other key-bindings then the default ones." https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/extragear-utils/krusader/key_bindings.html

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I searched that binding everywhere in `Shortcuts and Gesture` and `Window Behavior` (which also have some shortcuts there). I fixed Ctrl+Alt+L and Alt+Click there but I really couldn't find Ctrl+Alt+Right/Left and Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Right/Left

Comment: did you also check that your installation of IntelliJ IDEA maps those shortcuts? Sometimes software maps different keys when in different platforms (for example windows vs linux, in one the shortcut is one combination and in the other it's a different combination to do the same thing)

Comment: long ago when I used KDE, ctrl+alt+(left/right/up/down) was used to navigate multiple desktops. Maybe check the settings there instead of the general KDE settings. :) (I personally would never give up that, I love multiple desktops and can't live without it, and I got very used to those shortcuts ;) )

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking a look at JuK or other music players, as music players commonly use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ (<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>) to switch to next or previous tracks. At least that solves my problem.

The Kwin desktop switching has no default keybindings on my machine (I'm using KDE Plasma 5 on Arch Linux and it might be different from KDE4)

For KDE, you can view all registered Global Keyboard Shortcuts through the following process: `Settings -> System Settings -> Shortcuts and Gestures -> Global Keyboard Shortcuts`. You can check there to see which program is using this key binding.

Also, as a last resort (if you still cannot find what program is using the key combination), you can change the IntelliJ IDEA keymap. Say, redefining the navigation keybinding to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ (<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>) and see if that works for you.